# Accessing biome-specific grass tints w/out use of external programs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I am asking here is simple, is there any way through a command or something, to access the biome-specific grass tints? If it can only be done through the use of external programs, fine. But that's not what I am looking for. I am wondering if there is a way to do it in-game. If it does require an external program though, please link to link to that program. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Fungo:

> Since grass blocks all have the same block ID and no metadata, they will always be the color of the biome they are placed in. ALWAYS. No matter how you get them. ALWAYS.

I remember using Toomanyaddons and Tekkit to be able to spawn in various grass colors, but Tekkit is not vanilla Minecraft so that is not a reasonable solution to your problem.

Comment: Can I have an example of a command to spawn in a custom tinted grass block?

Comment: Edited for you.

Comment: that just gives you grass. It will still be the color of whatever biome it is currently in.

Comment: since grass blocks all have the same block ID and no metadata, they will always be the color of the biome they are placed in. ALWAYS. No matter how you get them. ALWAYS.

Comment: @Fungo so, I would have to use an external program to modify what biome a certain area is?

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  It appears I'm using Toomanyitems which gives grass blocks of different color.  But you're right, Fungo - I will include that in my edited answer.

Comment: Pretty much. You might be able to change the biome per block depending on what version/editor you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The different appearances of grass is hard coded into the engine. The game checks the texture pack and then applies a biome specific filter to color it. Normally in terrain.png the grass texture is greyscale to allow for these changes, but if you color the image for a new texture pack you can make it be variants of a color you choose. (As far as I know there is no way to make it stop)